# Abstract Class Issue with Assignment

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class, abstract

I'm attempting to do the following to my classes below...

Modify your super Vehicle class to make it abstract.

Modify the Motorized class by giving it an abstract method called "normalizedPower()" which returns a double.

normalizedPower will be calculated differently for cars and trucks.
For Automobiles, the normalized power is the horsepower divided by 150.

For Trucks, the normalized power is based on number of wheels.
For trucks with fewer than 12 wheels, the normalized Power is horsepower divided by 250.
For trucks with 12 or more wheels, the normalized power is horsepower divided by 400.

Code:

```
abstract class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> //changed to abstract
{
    String description;
    String idNumber;
    int numWheels;

    public Vehicle(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels)
    {
        description = aDescription;
        idNumber = aIdNumber;
        numWheels = aNumWheels;
    }
    void setDescription (String aDescription)
    {
        description = aDescription;
    }
    void setIdNumber (String aIdNumber)
    {
        idNumber = aIdNumber;
    }
    void setNumWheels (int aNumWheels)
    {
        numWheels = aNumWheels;
    }
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
    public String getIdNumber()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
    public int getNumWheels()
    {
        return numWheels;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d",idNumber,description,numWheels);
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vehicle other) {

        return description.compareTo(other.getDescription());
    }

}
class humanPowered extends Vehicle
{
    int calories;
    public humanPowered(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, int aCalories)
    {
        super(aDescription,aIdNumber,aNumWheels);
        calories = aCalories;
    }
    void setCalories (int aCalories)
    {
        calories = aCalories;
    }
    public int getCalories()
    {
        return calories;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d Calories per Hour: %d",idNumber,description,numWheels, calories);
        return result;
    }
}
abstract class Motorized extends Vehicle // changed to abstract
{
    double horsepower;
    public Motorized(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, double aHorsepower)
    {
        super(aDescription,aIdNumber,aNumWheels);
        horsepower = aHorsepower;
    }
    public double getHorsepower()
    {
        return horsepower;
    }
    abstract double normalizedPower(); //abstract method

    void setHorsepower(double aHorsepower)
    {
        horsepower = aHorsepower;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d Horsepower: %1.2f",idNumber,description,numWheels, horsepower);
        return result;
    }
}
class Automobile extends Motorized
{
    int passengers;
    double normalizedPower;
    public Automobile(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, double aHorsepower, int aPassenger)
    {
        super(aDescription,aIdNumber,aNumWheels, aHorsepower);
        passengers = aPassenger;
    }
    void setPassengers(int aPassengers)
    {
        passengers = aPassengers;
    }
    public int getPassengers()
    {
        return passengers;
    }

    double normalizedPower()
    {
        normalizedPower = horsepower/150;
        return normalizedPower;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d Horsepower: %1.2f Passengers: %d Normalized Power: %1.2f",idNumber,description,numWheels, horsepower, passengers, normalizedPower);
        return result;
    }
}
class Truck extends Motorized
{
    double GVW;
    double normalizedPower;
    public Truck(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, double     aHorsepower, double aGVW)
    {
        super(aDescription,aIdNumber,aNumWheels, aHorsepower);
        GVW = aGVW;
    }
    public double getGVW()
    {
        return GVW;
    }
    void setGVW (int aGVW)
    {
        GVW = aGVW;
    }

    double normalizedPower()
    {
        if (numWheels < 12)
        {
            normalizedPower = horsepower/250;
        }
        else
        {
            normalizedPower = horsepower/400;
        }
        return normalizedPower;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d Horsepower: %1.2f GVW: %1.2f Normalized Power: %1.2f",idNumber,description,numWheels, horsepower, GVW, normalizedPower);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID: MDB753 Description: A Wheels: 4 Horsepower: 160.00 Passengers: 6 Normalized Power:     0.00
ID: 267533 Description: H Wheels: 2 Calories per Hour: 320
ID: Unicycle Description: H Wheels: 1 Calories per Hour: 370
ID: 267533 Description: H Wheels: 2 Calories per Hour: 320
ID: AHB343 Description: T Wheels: 6 Horsepower: 280.00 GVW: 18.30 Normalized Power: 0.00
ID: BBR 332 Description: T Wheels: 4 Horsepower: 230.00 GVW: 5.34 Normalized Power: 0.00
ID: 993 RFT Description: T Wheels: 18 Horsepower: 424.00 GVW: 78500.00 Normalized Power: 0.00
```

I can't figure out why all the Normalized Power is printing out as 0.00. First time trying to implement abstract classes and methods so needless to say i'm a bit lost. Any and all help is much appreciated.

MAIN:

```
public class Hmwk {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        while (words.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = words.nextLine();
            String [] tokens;
            tokens = line.split("\t");
            String switchCase = tokens[0];
            char c = switchCase.charAt(0);
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'V':
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    String craftID2 = tokens[1];
                    int wheels2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    int cals = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
                    Vehicle aVehicle2 = new humanPowered (switchCase, craftID2, wheels2, cals);
                    list.add(aVehicle2);
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    String craftID3 = tokens[1];
                    int wheels3 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    double horses = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                    int passenger = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
                    Vehicle aVehicle3 = new Automobile (switchCase, craftID3, wheels3, horses, passenger);
                    list.add(aVehicle3);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    String craftID4 = tokens[1];
                    int wheels4 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    double horses2 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                    double gvw = Double.parseDouble(tokens[4]);
                    Vehicle aVehicle4 = new Truck (switchCase, craftID4, wheels4, horses2, gvw);
                    list.add(aVehicle4);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid data.");


            }
            Collections.sort(list);

        }
        for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you invoking `normalizedPower()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: From your code, it seems the field `normalizedPower` ins't actually initialized until you call the `normalizedPower()` method.

Comment: You should share your main method ...

Comment: Main has been added. And do you mean I should set `normalizedPower=0`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you would benefit from [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/). You include a lot of code here that is actually irrelevant to the problem, that makes it difficult for us as volunteer helpers to spot your problem. Good luck here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`normalizedPower` should not be a member to avoid inconsistent data and you would see the missing call to `normalizedPower()` in your `toString()` implementation.